# How do you retrieve a list of ALL Stripe paymentMethods?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) says to use the following if you want a specific customer's payment methods ...

```php
$stripe->customers->allPaymentMethods(
  'cus_Hjrd3I2sHt12Rf',
  ['type' => 'card']
);
```

... and then shows the following for how to return all payment methods:

```php
$stripe->paymentMethods->all([
  'customer' => 'cus_Hjrd3I2sHt12Rf',
  'type' => 'card'
]);
```

What I want is this ...

```php
$stripe->paymentMethods->all([
  'type' => 'card'
]);
```

... however this doesn't work. It spits out ...

```
{
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "\/v1\/payment_methods"
}
```

... but does fine when the `customer` is included (there are thousands of records).

**How do I retrieve ALL payment methods, not just a single customers?**

**Bonus round**: How do you constrain all results by date, so I can retrieve all payment methods added within the last X days? The usual `['created' => ['gte' => 1668595343]]` doesn't work as expected.

**Note**: Every other `$stripe->BLAH->all( ['created' => ['gte' => 1668595343]] )` I've tried appears to work correctly. Only `paymentMethods` seems to deviate.

Comment: It's true, I COULD do that (retrieve all customer), but this is super inefficient. I should be able to grab all payment methods, as I can grab all other datasets with `->all()`, constrained by `created`, etc. I'm looking for an elegant solution, not a workaround :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context, https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list only works if you're using Stripe Treasury.

> Returns a list of PaymentMethods for Treasury flows. If you want to
> list the PaymentMethods attached to a Customer for payments, you
> should use the List a Customer’s PaymentMethods API instead.

Since you're not using Stripe Treasury, PaymentMethods can only be listed per Customer.

So the only way for you to retrieve all PaymentMethods is to [list all Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list), [iterate through each Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto), and [list their PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list).

Example

```
$customers = $stripe->customers->all();

foreach ($customers->autoPagingIterator() as $customer) {
  $paymentMethods = $stripe->customers->allPaymentMethods(
    $customer->id,
    ['type' => 'card']
  );
  foreach ($paymentMethods->autoPagingIterator() as $paymentMethod) {
    echo $paymentMethod;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! An excellent, thorough answer, thank you. Is there any way to constrain that with a `created` date, so I only get, for example, payment methods created within the last 24 hours?

Comment: unfortunately not, the Stripe API doesn't provide parameters that allow you to list PaymentMethods created within a certain time range

Comment: What about this? You can get a list of payment methods enabled on the Dashboard:
https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_method_configurations/list?shell=true&api=true&resource=payment_method_configurations&action=list